# XML XSD Error : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'Config' must be from the schema namespace

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xsd

I have a very simple XML & XSD which is throwing following error during parsing.

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of
>   element 'Config' must be from the schema namespace,
>   'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.

**XML Goes here :**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
 <Config>

        <Test Script="final.sh" />

    </Config>
```

**XSD Goes here:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="Config">
        <xs:complexType>

        <xs:all> 
            <xs:element name="Test" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="Script" type="xs:string" use="required" />          

                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

        </xs:all>

        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Use SW such as Oxygen to help you spot your errors. I think you miss namespace declaration in your xml file, put it into your root element, something like this:  <Config xmlns:xs="http://
www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> . Plus add document declaration to the věry top of your xml file.

Comment: can you give me the modification please ?

Comment: Tru this or something similar: <Config xmlns:xs="http://
www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"></Config>

Comment: Also you can put this <?xml version="1.0"
encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> to the věry top of your xml file.

Comment: Look to this resource so that you know what you are doping wrong www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Comment: @i-bob : I did both the things you suggested. Not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it out in Oxygen and document was valid.

here are the two files I used:

**xsd file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 

<Config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='schema.xsd'>

    <Test Script="final.sh" />

</Config>
```

**xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   
    <xs:element name="Config">
        <xs:complexType>

            <xs:all> 
                <xs:element name="Test" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="Script" type="xs:string" use="required" />          

                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

            </xs:all>

        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Make sure you attach xsd schema to xml file correctly, then it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The instance document supplied is valid against the schema supplied, so there's something strange going on here.

The error message would seem to suggest that the schema you are actually validating against says

```
targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

which would be a rather odd thing for it to say.

I'm afraid you've been given a lot of very poor advice in other responses to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. should i remove targetNamespace then ?

Comment: If there is a targetNamespace in your schema (which there isn't in the schema you showed us) then it should not be there, because the document instance is not in a namespace.

Comment: If you removed targetNamespace then the code you showed us was not the code that failed. You can't expect us to help you debug your code if it is different from the code that you show us.

Comment: I am trying to resolve the  problem why is it happening?

Comment: I do not know why it is happening. Until you supply reliable information about the problem, I cannot possibly help you resolve it.

Answer (score -1):

missing root namespace, add it to it

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Robert : Can you help me with answer please ?